# Is there a way to do an `extern alias` inside a razor (MVC3) view?

Tags: c#, razor, alias, extern

Is there a way to do an `extern alias` inside a razor (MVC3) view?

I have two versions of the same assembly (i.e. 1.0 and 2.0) with a type that has the same name and namespace and I need a way to specify the newer one in the razor view.

I've tried:

```
@extern
```

and:

```
@{ extern alias MyAlias; }
```

But neither of those worked.

Comment: It can't

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823342/external-razor-views-cant-see-external-models

Answer (score 0):

<s>More than ten years later, but I did find a solution. There is still no "true" `extern alias` in Razor, but C# 10 did introduce `global using`, which together with namespace aliases can be used as a workaround.</s>

Technically, the statement go anywhere, but the entry point of the application is the most natural place to put it. So, in `Program.cs` or `App.cs` or the equivalent, at the top of the file put

```cs
extern alias MyAlias;
global using __MyAlias = MyAlias::My.Alias;
```

Now, all C# files, including files auto-generated by Razor, will be able to use `__MyAlias` in place of `MyAlias::My.Alias`. Unfortunately, a `using` alias can't then be used in a new `using` statement, so you'll have to do this with every fully-qualified-namespace in the colliding assembly.

The other alternative is to split your C# code from your `.razor` file into a separate `.razor.cs` file, where you can use C# normally; but this won't let you import components from an aliased assembly.

---

Unfortunately, I have to retract this answer, as upon further testing it only appeared to fix the issue. In particular, it doesn't in fact extend to component `.razor` files, which are the most crucial. (In all other cases we can just make a code-behind file and use `extern alias` normally). Perhaps this false start might help someone else find a solution, so I'm leaving it up.

Answer (score -1):

In the "web.config" file in "Views" directory of your project.Find this section.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      .
      .
      <!-- etc -->
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

you can add your custom namespace like this:

```
<add namespace="My.Custom" />
```

That will add the namespace to all of Razor(.cshtml or .vbhtml) files.

Comment: This is not what he's asking. He wants an alias. Doing what you suggest would have the same result as `@using My.Custom` in the view itself.